# Fill entire tabItem window in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I've looked at some similar questions, but haven't had luck with other solutions. I am trying to have the uiOutput/htmlOutput of a tabItem in Shiny Dashboard show a full network from the package netCoin. For the life of me, I can't figure out why this won't work. Reproducible example below:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(netCoin)

ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Example", tabName = "example", icon = icon("user"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "example",
              fillPage(
                tags$style(type = "text/css", "#fullpage {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
                uiOutput("fullpage")
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  output$fullpage = renderUI({
    frame <- data.frame(A = c("Man; Women", "Women; Women",
                              "Man; Man", "Undet.; Women; Man"))
    data <- dichotomize(frame, "A", sep = "; ")[2:4]
    C <- coin(data) # coincidence matrix
    N <- asNodes(C) # node data frame
    E <- edgeList(C) # edge data frame
    net = netCoin(N, E) # netCoin object
    shinyCoin(net)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The current output looks like this, though I'm aiming for it to fill the whole page:

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you are getting. I get an empty page with `'Not found'` in it.

Comment: @RonakShah Do you have the netCoin package installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed that package.

Comment: @ronakshah do you get that for the entire app or just within the tabItem frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to modify the iframe tag in the include.html netCoin package folder located at /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/netCoin/www and included the argument height:100%.

It now reads:

```
<iframe class="netcoin" style="border:none;overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%;min-height:400px;" src="index.html"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe.netcoin');
  iframe.style.height = iframe.offsetWidth/1.41 + "px";
}
</script>
```